# Как расставить запятые?

Tags: пунктуация

"Но с другой стороны, — каких физических сил стоит прожить всю жизнь как на спортивном состязании!" - нужно ли тут выделять запятыми "с другой стороны", особенно интересует запятая перед тире.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С ОДНОЙ СТОРОНЫ...С ДРУГОЙ СТОРОНЫ - это вводные слова, они обособляются. После союза НО запятая тоже нужна. Ср.:С одной стороны, ты прав, но, с другой стороны, ты должен принять во внимание и мою точку зрения. (пример взят из ПАС Лопатина) Интонационное тире, я думаю,  не нужно ставить, так как логическое ударение и без него падает на выражение "каких физических сил".

***Но, с другой стороны, каких физических сил стоит прожить всю жизнь как на спортивном состязании!***

Answer (score 1):

с одной стороны, он хороший человек, а с другой - идиот!

Comment: Хотелось бы видеть более подробное изложение этой мысли